# Ext.tip.Tooltip with a combobox losing focus

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I've configured a rich tooltip with a combobox on it. When I open up the combobox by clicking, the tooltip loses focus and closes. This behaviour is needed when I click outside of the tooltip and not within the tooltip.

How can I prevent closing the tooltip when losing focus inside the tooltip itself?

snippet:

```
var tip = Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
    autoHide: false,
    items: [{
        xtype: 'combobox',
        ...
    }]
});

Ext.QuickTips.init();
tip.show();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen to `beforehide` event and return false when you want to keep tip visible, but there is no access to mouseevent.

Another solution (IMO easier) is to override `onDocMouseDown` method on `Ext.tip.ToolTip`.
Example:

```
onDocMouseDown: function(e) {
    var combo = this.down('combo');

    if (!e.within(combo.getPicker().el)) {
        //this.callParent(arguments); 
        Ext.tip.ToolTip.prototype.onDocMouseDown.call(this, e);
    }
}
```

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/7NWr5/8/

Comment: The JSFiddle looks clean and simple! This solution is what I need. Thanks LoLo.

Comment: I see you edited your answer and the fiddle is not behaving correctly. The tooltip doesn't close when clicked outside of it and `me` is not referenced.

Comment: I made some typos - now fixes :) This I think is clener way for doing that.